# How can I get the content of a mini panel that is limited to admin-only access using a scheduled rules component?

Tags: rules

I'm using Rules to e-mail myself the content of a Mini Panel, which contains several views that are restricted to admin-only access.

I am using a component (Action set) that consists of two actions:

- **Send e-mail**
- **Schedule component evaluation** (re-schedule the same component to be evaluated the following day)

For **Send e-mail**, the body of my message looks like this (based on [this code](http://drupal.org/node/1178818#comment-6692720)):

```
<?php $block = module_invoke('panels_mini', 'block_view', 'admin_user_role_statistics'); print $block['content']; ?>
```

When I first triggered this component (using a rule that I created to trigger the component for the first time by viewing a user profile), I was logged in as an administrator, so the e-mail I received shows all of the content of the mini panel as I expected.  However, the following day, when the scheduled component was evaluated, the body of the e-mail message was blank, presumably because it was not sent by an admin user.

I re-enabled the rule to trigger the component and tried it as a non-admin user: the message body was empty.  I then tried it as an administrator: the message had the full content.

So, what can I do to make sure the component is evaluated as if triggered by an admin user?

Comment: So the actions are being executed by he who triggers the rule ? How is your component triggered ?

Comment: The problem is when the component is triggered by rules scheduler, which apparently triggers the component as an anonymous user...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be an anonymous user triggering the component and since you want an admin user to run the component, you will have to *impersonate* the admin user.

Try this code inside your components to *impersonate* the admin user :

```
global $user;
// Save the current user
$current_user = $user;
// Save user session
$current_session = drupal_save_session();
// From now on we don't want to save the session, since it would be unsafe
drupal_save_session(FALSE);
// We impersonate admin user
$user = user_load(1);
// Do wathever needs to be done.
// ...
// Now let's restore the triggering user and session.
$user = $current_user;
drupal_save_session($current_session);
```

Comment: I added this code, inserting the line from my question to print the block.  However, unfortunately this did not work for me; I still get an e-mail with nothing in the body.

Comment: Somehow I failed to add `global $user;` when I cut and paste the code.  I got it working using the example you provided... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://drupal.org/node/218104#comment-5330952) has more detail about how to set  up rules scheduler to run as admin. (Wouldn't it be nice if someone made a module to solve this problem?)